# Use 'pytest' to test if log output is coloured

Tags: pytest

Using `pytest`, is it possible to test that log output contains text of a certain colour?

For example, I've configured logging so that `logging.debug()` to output in purple, therefore I would expect the colour code for purple (`\33[035m`) to appear in the captured logs.

However, using the example below, the test fails. Note that in reality, the log prints with the purple colour as expected.

Is it possible to do this, and if so how can I amend my code to test for a colour code?

```py
class TestLogging:

    def test_colour(self, caplog):
        logger = Logger('pytest', verbose=True, use_colour=True).logger
        with caplog.at_level(logging.DEBUG):
            logger.debug('Test debug colour')

        assert ('\33[035mDEBUG\33[0m') in caplog.text
```

Comment: have you inspected `caplog.text`? What does it contain?

Comment: It contains the text expected, but the check for the colour code fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two things stopping me here -

1. The colour code was being changed on the fly from `\33[035m` to `\x1b[035m`. As this was happening anyway, I updated all of my colour codes to match.
2. Caplog text seems to log in a format that differs from my log format, and it seems to strip colour codes. Instead, I'm using `caplog.records[0].levelname`

```py
class TestLogging:

    def test_colour(self, caplog):
        logger = Logger('pytest', verbose=True, use_colour=True).logger
        with caplog.at_level(logging.DEBUG):
            logger.debug('Test debug colour')

        level_name = caplog.records[0].levelname
        assert '\x1b[035mDEBUG\x1b[0m' in caplog.records[0].levelname
```